# Laptop have black shadow bands arising from bottom of display

Tags: display

This is only noticed on dim screen as the brightness is increased this will not be noticed anymore. Is this any issue with my laptop display because it is in warranty.

[image: Photo of problem]

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question to make the photo an inline image. (You will gain that ability yourself when you have earned some reputation points on this site).

Comment: This is normal on many displays, including high-end TVs, when the backlight or brightness is set near `0`. It would still be prudent to check with the OEM's tech support, but more likely than not, this is normal.

Comment: My "solution" to this is to set up all my apps with "dark mode".  (Okay, I like dark mode anyhow, so I'm not filling the screen with white, eye-burning pixels all the time, but it's a side benefit.)  Obviously it's a matter of taste, but you will find that it's far less noticeable against dark colors than light...

Answer (score 5):

It's certainly not a normal behavior and might indicate a problem with
the monitor's back-lighting.

As it's under warranty, I wouldn't think twice and demand a replacement.

Only if the same problem occurs with the replacement laptop,
the conclusion would be that it's a general problem with this model.
It's then up to you to demand whatever you can under the warranty,
if possible up to asking for reimbursement.

(Just my personal attitude: In such a case I usually ask for
reimbursement and buy another model.
I don't like a model that already has a problem out-of-the-box,
and asking for a replacement might make a reimbursement
impossible.)

Comment: I do think it's been there from forever on my 2 year old laptop. But i was trying my best to avoid noticing it. I have already contacted the service team for the same.

Comment: If it is an inbuilt deficiency of this model, there is not much that can be done.

Comment: I have seen this plenty of times with cheap, low quality LCD displays. A same model replacement laptop will have the same issue, because it is a design flaw in the LCD panel they use. (Too few backlight leds and a diffuser screen that can't fully correct that. ) If you're  lucky you might a replacement that has a LCD panel from a different batch that might be a little better.

Comment: But it won't go worse than this, right like that flexgate issue with macbooks?

Comment: Poor light uniformity can be a real problem for lower quality LCD screens, there's not much to be done about it. It can vary greatly between individual units of the same model. It could also be that the edge led strip has some bad LEDs, but that would also show on higher brightness.  The banding pattern does indicate the LEDs are poorly matched, but if it only shows on a dimly light white background, it doubt they will fix it under warranty. You  can also ask how much of a problem it is to you if you dont notice it under normal use.

Comment: No mine one only shows on poor brightness, with increased brightness it acts normal

Comment: We cannot answer if it can get any worse. If you haven't noticed it before, one explanation would be that it's getting worse (or perhaps not).

Comment: @harrymc This is normal on many displays, including high-end TVs, when the backlight or brightness is set near `0`. It would still be prudent to check with the OEM's tech support, but more likely than not, it's normal due to the way LED screens are lighted.